# TortoiseGit doesn't work with msys2 git

Tags: ssh, git, tortoise-git, msys2

Recently, I've been looking into using TortoiseGit. I want to use it with msys2 instead of git for windows. I've set up an ssh key pair and configured it properly, as well as add a `HOME` environment variable set to `C:\Users\<Username>` (So that the ~ directory in mingw is the same as the `HOME` that TortoiseGit uses). I keep getting this error message:

```
error: cannot run C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe: No such file or directory
```

I've tried quite a few things, but no matter what I do, I continue to get this error. **How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug (https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3543) which is fixed in 2.10.0.1.